# how to search for multiple lines in a file and comment those lines in bash/dash

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk, grep

I have a file with contents

```
abc dbw ;\
xxx{ sample test } 
bewolf \
bewolf 
test
```

I need to check for

```
 xxx{ sample test }
 bewolf
```

and comment out these line like

```
/*xxx{ sample test }
bewolf*/
```

I have tried with `grep` but `grep` searches for string. As Dash script does not have arrays it makes it an even tougher job.

I was trying to get the starting and end index so that I can cut out that section using `head` and `tail`.

Any other ideas like using `sed` and `awk` are welcomed.

To be more general, I need to comment one macro in a C file using a Bash script.

Comment: Can you use Bash or not? Your question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If multiple end comments don't bother you, you could use a simple `sed` like this:

`sed -e "s%^xxx{ sample test }$%\/\*&\*\/%" -e "s%^bewolf$%\/\*&\*\/%" file.txt`

input:

```
abc dbw ;\
xxx{ sample test }
bewolf \
bewolf
test
```

output:

```
abc dbw ;\
/*xxx{ sample test }*/
bewolf \
/*bewolf*/
test
```

Add the `-i` flag if you would like to overwrite `file.txt` directly.

Comment: all the answers are right, but what if i need to comment a 10 lines of code in more than 50 files

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to comment the lines which are having :

*xxx{ sample test }

bewolf*

```
awk '{if($0~/bewolf/ || $0~/xxx{ sample test }/)print "//"$0;else print}'
```

**Test:**

```
    > awk '{if($0~/bewolf/ || $0~/xxx{ sample test }/)print "//"$0;else print}' temp
    abc dbw ;\
//    xxx{ sample test } 
//    bewolf \
//    bewolf 
    test
```

Answer (score 0):

even shorter:

```
awk '/sample test/,/bewolf/' infile >outfile
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that doesn't do what the OP wants.  They want to *comment out* those lines, not print them.

Comment: yet Tim pote you are right , all i needed is to comment one region in one c file

Answer (score 0):

The following will modify the section starting with a line matching  and ending with a line matching  to add a single "/*" at the beginning and a single "*/" at the end.

```
awk -vstart=xxx -vend=bewolf '$0~start {$0="/*" $0;inmacro=1} inmacro==1 && $0~end {$0=$0 "*/";inmacro=0} {print}' infile > outfile
```

This may be closer to what you are looking for. Of course you may make it shorter if you don't define variables bur hardcode them in the instructions instead.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 sed '/^xxx{ sample test }/!b;:a;$b;N;/.*\nbewolf *$/!ba;s//\/* & *\//' file
```

Explanation:

- Focus on lines beginning `xxx{ sample test }`. `/^xxx{ sample test }/!b`
- Create a loop label `:a`
- If it's end of file bail out. `$b`
- Get next line. `N`
- Check for line ending in `bewolf` and if not get next line i.e loop to `a`. `/.*\nbewolf *$/!ba`
- Surround the pattern space with comments and print out. `s//\/* & *\//`